# SSH Communication Using Public and Private Keys

Tags: security, unix, ssh, public-key-encryption, openssh

I am trying to understand how SSH authorization method work because I am trying to setup an git server using gitolite.

As far as I know gitolite will use the ssh to authorize users and give access to them to a specific repository with personal write and read permissions. But I am confused about how the authorization will work.

I've watched some videos in YouTube and they use some analogy with colors to explain. If I understand right, for two persons that are going to communicate between each other in a secret way, they need a secret and public key.

The two persons know each other public keys, and to communicate between each other they agree to use one public key. To establish a connection they encrypt they private key using the same public key and send the result to each other. When they receive the result they add the private key to that message and like magic they got the same message.

But I don't think I understand this right because I can't see how the server will verify the the client. I know the server had to hold the public keys from the clients that will connect to him, but he also got a private key?

When the client tries to connect to a server, he sends his private key encrypted with his public key, and the server encrypt his private key using the client public key and send to the client?

How the server check if the user is really him? I also read that to decrypt the information encrypted with a public key, only the person that holds the private key can decrypt the message. So how the server can decrypt the message send by the client if he don't have the client private key?

If someone could explain me how the authentication, authorization, and exchange of information work using this public and private keys I would be very happy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSH works roughly like the following.  Note that this is merely a high level explanation:

Each party has two keys:  a public key and a private key.  The public/private keys are related  mathematically, such that they are functionally inverse.  Thus an operation performed by one can only be undone exactly by the other.  It is complex, but think of it like calculating x^nnn versus the nnnth root of x.  The former is easy but the latter is difficult, making it computationally unfeasible to guess with enough accuracy to undo the operation.  This gives us some desirable attributes that allow  SSH to do the following with them:

The client connects to the server.  The server proves its identity by presenting a certificate signed with its private key.  The client uses the server's public key to decrypt the certificate and knows that only the client could have encrypted it since it requires the private key.  The server then does the same with a certificate presented by the client.  Identification can only be performed with 100% assurance using a trusted third party to manage the public keys.  Without the third party only identity changes can be detected.

Now that identities are verified, the server generates a symmetric secret key, encrypts it with the client's public key, and send it to the client (who is the only one that can decrypt the message since it requires the private key).  From this point on, both the client and server have the symmetric secret key, and all communication is encrypted with this key.  This is done for performance reasons because symmetric encryption operations are roughly 100 times faster than asymmetric operations.

This is how SSL verifies identities, and encrypts the information.  Note that more granular access control are provided by higher level applications (such as *nix file permissions), not SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of this subject is a little bit excessive for Stackoverflow format.

Few days ago Coursera started a free course on Cryptography (part I) that explains exactly the matters you are interested in.

I welcome you to [cryptography course](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto) to find the answers for your questions